# Assign 100% height to a div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a similar problem like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128226/problem-using-jquery-to-animate-div-to-100-height)

I want to animate a div, to a css property of 100% height.
This doesnt seem to work:

```
$("#somediv").css('height', '100%');
```

Is there a way to solve this other than slidedown/up?

Comment: It most likely is working. To set 100% height on an element, **all** parent elements must have an explicit height set.

Comment: What Rory said, you should go up the parents tree and set heights. 100% is relative height of the parent element.

Comment: By 100% do you mean the height of the entire window, or the height of the closest parent element?

Comment: Sorry, my question was for OP.

Comment: Ups, my bad. Wasn't careful.

Comment: @PerSalbark It has to be the size of the amount of information inside the div. So basically 100%

Comment: @Max: Still not getting it. Anyway, Patrick just posted an answer for getting the same height as the closest parent element. So now you have both answers. Choose the one that suits you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the parent height like this:

```
$("#somediv").css('height', $("#somediv").parent().height());
```

Or put an id on the div you can get the height

```
$("#divtogethigger").css('height', $("#iddivheight").parent().height());
```

if you want to animate it:

```
$('#somediv').animate({
    height: $(this).parent().height()
  }, 5000, function() { 
    // Animation complete.
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Just set the div to be the window's height

```
$("#somediv").height($(window).height());
```

If you do not do this, you need all of the parent elements to have an explicit height set in order to use `height: 100%;`

Comment: Plus `$(window).height()` returns integer. You need to add ` + 'px'`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, the div doesn't do anything at all. Even with an extra ')' ;)

Comment: @Neal What do you mean no, you don't? If you assign an integer value to a height CSS property, nothing will happen. It must have a unit or %.

Comment: @neal it works now, however it makes the div the size of the window which isn't the effect I'm after.

Comment: @MaxvanHeiningen well you did not specify the height. your OP said 100% so I guessed.

Answer (score 1):

```
var somediv = $("#somediv");
somediv.css('height', somediv.parent().height());
```

Comment: as marcel said you may need the px:  somediv.css('height', somediv.parent().height() + 'px');